# Can we reproduce the same benchmarking results for a stochastic algorithm, using the same random seed but on different machines?

Tags: random, stochastic

I am testing a stochastic algorithm. To make the results reproducible, I plan to  use the same random seed and include this seed number (an integer) together with the benchmark results when they are published.

But I have a naive question regarding the random seed. Are others with a different machine guaranteed to reproduce my results if they use the same random seed?  In fact, I have little knowledge about the principle  about random seeds. Admitted, many websites explain it in a more or less elaborated manner, but maybe you have some thinking on that topic to share with?

Concretely, I have a python project that is based on [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) procedures. I will use `numpy.random.seed(42)` for my published benchmark results, and expect others to have the same results as in my machine, as long as the same seed number is used. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "Will the same Algorithm, correctly compiled and executed, running on different Machines (Computer, Abacus, or 'Counting Sticks') provide exactly the same number (subject to FP error and rounding)", then the answer is yes.

If you mean more literally "... would it be identical. Can I order a McDonald's Burger at Wendy's (or even cook it there) and will it be identical", then the answer is no.

More precisely, "The Benchmark result will not be the same on different Machines (even two Computers with exactly the same Model Number) except for rare coincidence (which is more likely to occur than comparing entirely different Machines, IE: Multiplication speed of an Abacus vs. a Calculator). The number (answer) derived from the same Algorithm (method) will be the same (subject to FP error and rounding) but the "Benchmark" will almost always not be the same.

Comment: Especially with modern hardware architectures which auto-scale up and down to adjust for heat generated. (CPUs and especially GPUs) The 'calculations' will be the same on both machines (like @Rob said, ignoring possible floating point errors, etc) however, the progress made per machine won't be uniformly distributed over time. Some machines will slow down when they get too hot, and speed back up when they cool down, etc. Other issues could be 'other processes' on each machine, etc.